# Confused About Squareroots & Absolute Values

Tags: calculus

$${ x }^{ 2 }=4\\ \sqrt { { x }^{ 2 } } =\sqrt { 4 } \\ |x|=2$$
According to my professor, in the above case, the absolute value gives two solutions: $x=±2$
Consider the discriminant in the quadratic formula: $$x=\frac { -b±\sqrt { { b }^{ 2 }-4ac }  }{ 2a } \\ Let\quad { z }^{ 2 }={ b }^{ 2 }-4ac\\ ±\sqrt { { b }^{ 2 }-4ac } \\ =±\sqrt { { z }^{ 2 } } \\ =±|z|\\ =±z$$
However, according to my professor, in this case, the absolute value gives only one solution: $|z|=z$

How come the absolute value sometimes gives one solution and sometimes it gives two solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Let's check this out, backwards, checking to see that the solutions $x = 2$ and $x = -2$ satisfy $|x| = 2$:

\begin{align}
x &= 2: \quad &|2| &= 2 \\ \\
x &= -2: \quad &|-2| &= 2 \\ \\
\end{align}

There are TWO possible "input" values for $x$, such that $|x| = 2$. Note for each of the two inputs, the "output" is the same. Essentially the absolute value function can be described, defined as follows:

$\quad f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R,\;f(x) = |x|:$

- $\;x\mapsto -x\;\;$ *if and only if* $\;\;x \lt 0$,
- $\;x \mapsto x,\;\;\;\;$ otherwise

I'll include a graph of the function $$f(x) = y = |x|,\;\;\text{with}\;\;x = -2,\;\; x = 2,\;\; f(x) = y = 2\;\;$$ to help you visualize the symmetric function, its behavior, and why $$\;f(x) = y = |x| = 2\;\implies\;x = -2\;\;\text{or}\;\;x = 2\;:$$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Graph from [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%20=%20%7Cx%7C,%20x%20=%202,%20x%20=%20-2,%20y%20=%200,%20y%20=%202)

See also the following posts:

- [square root of a square is the same as absolute value?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258876/proving-square-root-of-a-square-is-the-same-as-absolute-value)
- [square roots: positive and negative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative?rq=1)

Comment: The reason there are two input values is because of this diagram, right? http://s8.postimage.org/5n3zn5g6t/Untitled.png

Comment: precisely, two different x-values: +x and -x  will have the same y value, for $x\neq 0$., in which case of $|0| = 0$, $\pm 0 = 0$ there is only one input with one output.

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that the absolute value doesn't give two solutions.
It's just that if you have $±|z|$ this can either be $-(±z)$ or $(±z)$, either way you still only get two cases; namely, $±z$.

[image]

If you understand the equation $y=|x|$ then you should be able to see that since $|x|$ takes two values of $x$, both positive and negative, $|-x|=|x|$. So when you put in $x=-2$ you get 2, which is the same as if you plug in $x=2$. So it's symmetric.

Comment: 1 more question: why do we bother with |x|? As shown in this diagram: http://s8.postimage.org/5n3zn5g6t/Untitled.png, the result will always be ±x, right?

Comment: But I mean: is there a reason to not shortcut it to just ±x? Is there any advantage to using |x| over ±x?

Comment: $|x|$ is an operation on $x$. We only say plus or minus $x$ if we're solving for $x$. We have to realize that $x$ could have been two values, $-x$ or $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute value is a single value. But there are two cases, when $x\geq0$, $|x|=x$ and when $x<0$, $|x|=-x$. Since there is $\pm$ sign in your second last line, it does not really matter to separate the two cases. So simply $\pm |z|=\pm z$.