# Another square root question...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know $(-7)^2=49$.

I know $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$

But how come if you take the root of both sides of the first line it looks like this:

$\sqrt{(-7)^2}=\sqrt{49}\longrightarrow-7=7$?

Comment: If you know that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, then you should automatically also know that $\sqrt{(-7)^2}=|-7|=7$, not $-7$...

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ is not an injective $1-1$ function on the real numbers

Comment: Because, as you state, $\sqrt x= |x| \rightarrow \sqrt{(-7)^2}=|-7|=7$.

Comment: The absolute value of both is equal. $\sqrt{(-7)^2}=\sqrt{49}=\text{POSITIVE}\boxed7$. But $-\sqrt{(-7)^2}=-\sqrt{49}=\text{NEGATIVE}\boxed7$. And |7|=|-7|=7$

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> $$\sqrt{(-7)^2}=\sqrt{49}\longrightarrow-7=7$$

But, you also wrote:

> $$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$$

So, how about:

$$\sqrt{(-7)^2}=\sqrt{49}\longrightarrow|-7|=7$$

Comment: But the reason $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ is because there are two potential solutions, not one. This relationship isn't an axiom or something like that, it's a relationship that was noticed due to the potential number of solutions. Your answer doesn't make sense to me. Arithmetic doesn't always work the same way as algebra. You're telling me that: $((-7)^2)^{1/2}=7$?

Comment: The absolute value is used because the codomain of the square root function is the non-negative reals. Negative solutions are not allowed. I did not choose to represent it this way. *You* did. I used the format you provided and substituted the digits. I'm sorry this doesn't make sense to you. :(

Comment: @zduff Yes, I'm telling you that $\sqrt {(-7)^2}=7$. That's how it's defined. Moreover, that's what you wrote when you wrote that $sqrt{x^2}=|x|. You said it before I did.

Comment: The part I don't understand is how: $\sqrt{(-7)^2}=((-7)^2)^{1/2}\neq((-7)^{1/2})^2$

Comment: I didn't choose to represent it that way. That's the way square root function is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found an answer that is satisfying. I realized that my conceptual problem was with the way square root functions are defined. They are defined to have a positive codomain so that they can remain a function. Here's a link:
[Proving square root of a square is the same as absolute value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258876/proving-square-root-of-a-square-is-the-same-as-absolute-value)

Comment: When you wrotr, "I know $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$
," I thought you were satisfied with that definition. Sounds like it's the definition that was creating the problem for you. Glad you found your answer.